# Disable submit button as default state until all inputs are filled in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to disable submitting the form until all fields are filled.

I've tried adding the `disable` option in the button but it doesn't work.

This is the form:

```
<form id="contactForm" name="contactForm" novalidate>
    <input type="text" name="contactName" id="contactName" placeholder="Nombre" data-ng-model="cu.contactName" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" required autofocus>
    <span style="color:red" ng-show="contactForm.contactName.$dirty && contactForm.contactName.$invalid">
        <span ng-show="contactForm.contactName.$error.required">El nombre es requerido.</span>
    </span>

    <button class="hvr-bounce-to-right" type="submit" ng-disabled="contactForm.contactName.$dirty && contactForm.contactName.$invalid" name="submit-form" ng-click="cu.sendMail()">Enviar mensaje &ensp; <span class="icon flaticon-envelope32"></span></button>
</form>
```

Right now, the button gets disabled when I start typing and then deletes everything in the input, when I try to click, it gets disabled, but what I want is that the button is disabled since the beginning and then when you fill the inputs it gets unlocked or un-disabled(if that's a word).

Please help, thanks!

Comment: Enabled is the word you were looking for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by adding this `$pristine` attribute:

`User has not interacted with the field yet.`

So my button looks now like this:

```
<button class="hvr-bounce-to-right" type="submit" ng-disabled="contactForm.contactName.$dirty && contactForm.contactName.$invalid || contactForm.contactName.$pristine" name="submit-form" ng-click="cu.sendMail()">Enviar mensaje &ensp; <span class="icon flaticon-envelope32"></span></button>
```

Now it is disabled from the start and only enables itself once the user interacts and fill the (in this case) `contactName` input.

Answer (score 1):

The angular docs are actually pretty decent for form state handling:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

Check the second-to-last example, where they display a message if the email is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Each state of every input should be reflected in the scope/controller.

So assuming you have this :

```
$scope.myInputs = {};
```

you should ng-model each input in the view to :

```
ng-model = "myInputs.email";
```

Then , using ng-blur/ng-change you should  iterate through each property in the  $scope.myInputs object to see if values are filled. only then you should control the disability of the submit.